# Why I cannot use react State hooks globally (outside class and function)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to test some code documentation on sandbox/another online fiddles, but those does not have class or even function other than `ReactDOM.render`, then I want to use the state component to test if it can be used in my code. How is it possible without creating a new class/function? If it is not possible in any way, why so?

Comment: docs have a clear exp [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

Comment: Let me ref you to [this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/a-quick-guide-to-testing-react-hooks-fa584c415407/) for the “how”. And for the “why”, because react hooks depend on a “driver” to provide the correct context for them to run. And `react-dom` is that driver.

Comment: I don’t wanna go lengthy explaining all details. But if you have time, as a mind exercise, you can try implement the hook mechanism from ground up, and you would find out the reason along the way. FYI, I did write a [hook lib](https://github.com/hackape/fn-with-hooks) of such kind for educational purpose.